# Payment gateway HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 51: SSL: certificate subject name 'seguro3.cpmp.com.gt' does not match target host name '190.0.195.24'

Tags: ssl, curl, openssl, nusoap

I am trying to connect a payment gateway to my website but I am a beginner, they sent me an example code and I adjusted it to my site but when I try to make a payment I get this error:
" wsdl error: Getting https://190.0.195.24:9001/paymentgw/services/paymentgw?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 51: SSL: certificate subject name 'seguro3.cpmp.com.gt' does not match target host name '190.0.195.24'
url: https://190.0.195.24:9001/paymentgw/services/paymentgw?wsdl"
This is my code:

```
require_once('./libsoap/nusoap.php');
        $url = "https://190.0.195.24:9001/paymentgw/services/paymentgw?wsdl";
        $client = new nusoap_client($url , 'wsdl' , false, false, false, false, 0, 25);
        $client->authtype = 'certificate'; 
        $client->certRequest['sslcertfile'] = '/var/www/vhosts/VisaKeys/iga.pem';
        $client->certRequest['sslkeyfile'] = '/var/www/vhosts/VisaKeys/iga.key';
        $client->certRequest['CACert'] = '/var/www/vhosts/VisaKeys/VisaNetCA.key'; 
        $client->certRequest['verifypeer']=0;
        $client->certRequest['passphrase']='pass';



        $err = $client->getError();
        if ($err) {
            // Display the error
            echo '<h2>Constructor error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
            // At this point, you know the call that follows will fail
        }

        if($result == FALSE)
        {

            echo "<center>";
            $result = $client->call('authorizationRequest', $params);
            $timing = time() - $start; // calculating the transaction time 
            //echo "<pre>".print_r($result, false) . "</pre>";
            echo "<h5>Finish time: " . time() . " <br>";
            echo "<h5>Total time: " . print_r($timing, true) . "<br>";
            echo "Hubo un Error en su transaccion por favor intente nuevamente";
            echo "<center>";
        }
        if ($client->fault) 
        {
            echo '<h2>Fault</h2><pre>';
            print_r($result);
            echo '</pre>';
        } 
        else 
        {
            // Check for errors
            $err = $client->getError();
            if ($err)
            {
                // Display the error
                echo '<h2>Error</h2><pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
            } 

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

SSL certificates validates domain names, not IP addresses. 
You need to ignore certificate errors, or replace 190.0.195.24 with a hostname for which the server has a valid certificate.

seguro3.cpmp.com.gt is a good guess :-)

seguro3.cpmp.com.gt.    5379    IN      A       190.0.195.24